# Find Element method is not throwing exception when elements are not there

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The `findElement(By.xpath(""))` method is not throwing exception and the program keeps waiting at that line and doesn't proceed further.

I also tried using `classname`,`cssSelector` but nothing helped.
In my html I don't have id for the element which I'm trying to capture.

his is my actual code where I'm testing for dropbox elements

```
public boolean dropBoxtest(WebDriver driver,String userQuery) 
{ 
 try
    { 
     driver.findElement(By .xpath("//div[@id='Panel']/span[2]/ul"));          
     List<WebElement> dropbox = driver.findElements(By .xpath("//div[@id='Panel']/span[2]/ul/li")); 
     if (!dropbox.isEmpty()) {    
     flag = false; do some operations here 
     }
     return flag; 
     catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    }
```

Please kindly help me on this issue.

Comment: are sure that empy xpath is the only way? Can you post HTML snippet you are trying to process, and your code?  [How to ask questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: try{driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='resultPanel']/span[2]/ul"));
   
List<WebElement> dropbox = driver.findElements(By
     .xpath("//div[@id='resultPanel']/span[2]/ul"));

Comment: This is my actual code where I'm testing for dropbox elements

public boolean dropBoxtest(WebDriver driver,String userQuery) {
   try{
   driver.findElement(By
     .xpath("//div[@id='Panel']/span[2]/ul"));
   
   List<WebElement> dropbox = driver.findElements(By
     .xpath("//div[@id='Panel']/span[2]/ul/li"));
   
   if (!dropbox.isEmpty()) {
    flag = false;
    
    do some operations here
   }
   return flag;
   catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
    
   }

Comment: I have added code in the question body. Before somebody answers it, they would require - i) the HTML of the page. and ii) the exception you are getting. Please add this description.

Comment: Xpath is known to be brittle and flaky. I do not understand why so many people ask questions how to use it, and why so many people suggest using it in the answer. If preferred locators (ids and names) are not available, use CSS locators.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you.   I think this explains why the .findElement did not return an exception; its because .findElements will never return an exception, but instead will return an empty list.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThisTestClass.class);
...
public Boolean dropBoxTest(WebDriver driver, String userQuery) 
{ 
   try {
       By ul = By.xpath(".//div[@id='Panel']/span[2]/ul");
       By li = By .xpath(".//li");
       By chained = new ByChained(ul, li);
       List<WebElement> dropbox = driver.findElements(chained); 
       if (!dropbox.isEmpty()) {    
         flag = Boolean.FALSE; 
       }
       return Boolean.TRUE;
   } catch (WebDriverException wde) { 
       LOGGER.info("Error finding element " + chained, wde);
       return Boolean.FALSE;
   } 
}
```

Also, look into using Selenide.